# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_curl.dll'

Tags: php, mysql, macos, apache

I am using a mac and I installed apache and php mysql natively. DLL is for windows not php. my php webservice works fine but when I run the php cli, I get the following error

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_curl.dll'
```

So my question is how do i get the cli to recognize my .so files instead.

Comment: How did you install PHP? Did you copy/paste your config from somewhere? I find it hard to believe that the default `php.ini` for OSX uses references dll files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change your php.ini file to not reference the DLL files.

Comment: The php.ini file doesn't include references to any .dll files, yet this error occurs.

Comment: +1 for providing an answer.. had no effect in my case of this exact same error message, due to no references to .dll files.  But, the problem disappeared as suddenly and nonsensically as it started.

Comment: dll files are for windows only. on mac, it has no business referencing it.

Comment: @numerical25 I stand corrected, after some further file searching (brute force, just trying to figure out how it was possible this problem occurred)  I found a reference to php_curl.dll.  Now I cannot understand how I missed this because I was searching all text files for the text string "php_curl". I spotted it by eye a minute ago.